# Pygtk TextView setting cursor at the beginning

Tags: python, textview, pygtk, cursor-position

I have a gtk.TextView() and every time the user puts text in it and hit return I want to print the text in the terminal and erase everything in the text area and so, put the cursor at the beginning of the textview. I tried to :

```
self.textbuffer.set_text("")
```

or :

```
start, end = self.textbuffer.get_bounds()
self.textbuffer.delete(start, end)
```

But both these codes even if they erase the text in the text area, they don't put the cursor back on the first line but instead it is on the second line. And if I type more text and return, it always stays on the second line, I don't know the reason why.

Well I didn't manage to do it so I used a trick for the time being, here it is :

```
self.textview = gtk.TextView()
self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
self.textview.connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press_event)
```

and my self.on_key_press_event :

```
def on_key_press_event(self,widget, event):
    keyname = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if keyname == "Return":
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        startiter, enditer = self.textbuffer.get_bounds()
        print self.textbuffer.get_text(startiter, enditer)
        self.textview.destroy()
        self.textview=gtk.TextView()
        self.sw.add(self.textview)
        self.textview.show()
        self.textview.grab_focus()
        self.textview.connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press_event)
```

So each time the user hit return I remove the textview from my gtk.ScrolledWindow , destroy it, create a new one and add it again in my gtk.ScrolledWindow, it works but it's really dirty...

Any idea of how I can make this work without that dirty code ?

Thanks in advance,

Nolhian

Comment: There is a Hello everybody at the start of my post but I don't know why it won't appear, I tried to edit my post 8 times but either Hello alone or Hello everybody get deleted :(

Comment: That's because this is not a forum; more like a wiki, somebody may edit your question at any time. That makes it difficult to think of a question as being a message from one single person; so salutations are discouraged. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 3):

Here is what is happening:

The user presses the enter key and your code is being run. The widget then takes over again and does what it always does when `Return` is pressed, which is to move the cursor to the next line.

But if you bind your command to the key *release* event,

```
self.textview.connect("key_release_event", self.on_key_press_event)
```

then your code is executed *after* the cursor has been moved to the next line, so `set_text("")` is all that is needed to clear the buffer and move the cursor to its start.